# Will vegetables grown where tobacco stems were chopped into the soil have any traces of nicotine?

Tags: vegetables, soil

My neighbor, while spreading a thick layer of tobacco stems across his pasture (I have no idea what for), got quite a few into my garden. I tried to remove it, but somehow a good amount has been chopped up with the soil this spring. Will that harm any of my vegetables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps he's aiming for organic matter / compost in his pasture? Seems like a good way to encourage stray deer to keep coming back! ;)

I don't know, but I doubt that your veg will take up any significant quantities of nicotine. A quick search didn't turn up any useful information about uptake by plants.

The main harm that comes to mind is the possible transmission of tobacco mosaic virus to your Solanaceaa (tomatoes, potatoes, pepper, eggplant).

Also, if there *is* any significant quantity of nicotine related to the stems in your garden, it could be harmful to your population of beneficial organisms.

Comment: Very good point re: the TMV

Comment: Last year many of his plants were virused when he harvested them. Good point. I'll have to plant my solanaceous plants elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Tobacco field’s are TOXIC! The different chemicals used on tobacco plants are deathly. The fields were sprayed with deadly chemicals to keep weeds down, kill the pesky tobacco worm, give the tobacco leaves a certain color, stop the growth on top of the tobacco plant, called a sucker. The chemicals are in the soil, just waiting to absorb into a vegetable. Chemicals will be in tobacco fields for century’s.

Comment: Some references for theses claims would be good.